# Flex : Disabled canvas look and feel

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, skin

```
Is there a way in Flex by which a disabled canvas looks exactly the same
as an enabled canvas? I haven't been able to make sense of disabledOverLayAlpha
and disabledColor properties for a Canvas component.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to mess with expected user experience (you may have a perfectly good reason to do so; just asking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ *Michael Todd*: There are many imaginative ways to show disabled status rather than using the default disabled over colour. For instance, you may want to disable a Canvas, but would prefer the child components to be bound to their parent and display their disabled states rather than make light of a container that the user may not even know exists and may cover an inappropriate area in comparison to the content at any given time.

@ *dta*: I'm working with a Canvas that will be dynamically enabled/disabled right now, the disabledColor property does not effect the colour of the disabledOverlay, use backgroundDisabledColor instead, setting disabledOverlayAlpha to 0 does make the disabledOverlay entirely transparent - thus the enabled and disabled states of the component look exactly the same. The disabledColor property changes the colour used by the Canvas's textFormater.

Running Flex SDK 3.4